# How to send keys in an Ajax dropdown?

Tags: selenium, python

[image]

I already got the Xpath, but when I'm trying send keys there is error :

```
 Error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Belajar1\Register.py", line 23, in test_register
self.email = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='email']").send_keys("dssdf")
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 334, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 460, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 188, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Help please. I am new in selenium with python.

Comment: This looks like a pop up box or a frame. Have you switched to the frame and then tried to enter the code?

Comment: yes, I already made code : switch to frame but didn't work.

Comment: Wait. It's not a pop- up. have you tried using the actions class to jump to this element. I think this is a hover over menu, which can be solved by using Actions.

Comment: do you mean using Actionchains?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Comment: tried, test passed. but nothing happen on Web, i mean send key doesn't work. 

Comment: Can you give me the URL.

Comment: https://www.mataharimall.com/ 
@log_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FDM mentioned the  `$x("//*[@id='email']")` will find 2 matching elements. So you need to build a locator that is more unique/precise. If you search it in Firebug or any other console you'll notice that it yields two matching nodes.

I'm not sure in Python how it should be, but I tried this in Java using the following CSS selector and it worked.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id=top-user-menu-wrapper] input[id=email]")).sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: thank you @ilm @FDM it's work. 

python :

`self.email = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id=top-user-menu-wrapper] input[id=email]")`

Comment: @Santi Your Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command in Chrome (F12 < Console):

```
$x("//*[@id='email']")
```

You will see that the page has **two elements with this identifier** (which is, in fact, not conforming to the meaning of `id`).

When the email field is visible, as in your screenshot, it is actually the **second** email field that you see.
But Selenium finds the **first** element which is invisible, and thus your code fails.

**Solution:** try making your XPath more specific.

Comment: I use path : $x("//*[@id='email']")

Comment: Well... that's probably the problem, if you read my answer carefully. :)

Comment: yes.. after analyze again, i get it.. sorry for my bad....  i am new in automation test. @FDM  